# Why is terbinafine hydrochloride cream OTC in the US whereas ciclopirox olamine cream isn't?

Tags: dermatology

Why is terbinafine hydrochloride cream OTC in the US whereas ciclopirox olamine cream isn't? Both medications are typically used to treat fungal skin infections (tinea corporis, tinea capitis, tinea pedis, tinea cruris, etc.). I wonder what makes ciclopirox olamine cream unsafe to be sold without some physician's consent.